# Recursive function used to detect suspect phrases PHP

Tags: php, forms, recursion

I am learning PHP and had a question when watching Lynda.com php tutorial.
https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Blocking-suspect-phrases/418256/452170-4.html?autoplay=true
The following is the code for detecting suspect phrases in online forms.
$value is the online form input value.

```
$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';            

function isSuspect($value, $pattern, &$suspect) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $item) {
            isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
        }
    } else {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
            $suspect = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I know function isSuspect is a recursive function.I don't understand why using this recursive function here and how it would affect the else{ } part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the function `isSuspect` the first time, it checks first if the `$value` is an array if so, it loops through the array (`foreach ($value as $item)`)... and calls the function again with any value of it. when there finally is the `$value` not an array anymore it goes into the `else` part. There it checks the pattern with `$value` and sets `$suspect` to `true` if it matches. You may ask yourself now, why is `$suspect` is outside of the function now also `true`. Well, look at the head of function. You notice the `&$suspect`. This is passing by reference. Review the manual regarding pass by reference:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It made me scratch my head for a long time and it finally makes sense.